# Multiple drop down lists and avoiding selecting an item twice

Tags: excel, list, validation, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a table of people where there are columns for a first and second preference eg:

```
Name        Favourite Fruit         Second Favourite Fruit
Person 1    Apple                   Banana
Person 2    Kiwi Fruit              Pear
```

What I am trying to do is prevent a preference being selected twice eg stop a user selecting Person 1's favourite as `apple` and also their second favourite as `apple`.

I am using Data Validation referring to a named range.

Is it possible to do this with a formula and not with Visual Basic?

In reality the list has 22 items, so it would be rather unwieldy to set up multiple lists depending on what was selected as the favourite.

Comment: without VBA you need to create a full list for every person... no workaround... to be correct: 2 lists for everyone (selecting "apple" in "second" should also disable it in "1st favorite")

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with without VBA, you'll have blank spots where the option used to be in the dropdown though.

```
     [A]    [B]                                                                                              [J]        [K]
1    Master DropdownList                                                                                     Choose A   Choose B
2    A      =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$J$2:$J$9,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$K$2:$K$9,1,FALSE),""))<>"","",A2)   
3    B      =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$J$2:$J$9,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$K$2:$K$9,1,FALSE),""))<>"","",A3) 
4    C      =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,$J$2:$J$9,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,$K$2:$K$9,1,FALSE),""))<>"","",A4) 
5    D      =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,$J$2:$J$9,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,$K$2:$K$9,1,FALSE),""))<>"","",A5)
```

Note: Data Validation for columns J and K in this example are $B2:$B5

Note2: The VLookup onl looks at J2:J9 and K2:K9, you'll need to expand this as you see fit, however you can drag the formula down and it should auto-fill.

Note3: As you select options in either column J or column K with the dropdown. Those options will turn to 'blank' or empty string dynamically.

Comment: you still have to do it for every person... choose `A` in `J2` disables it in `K3`

Answer (score 0):

OK, while there are several ways to solve this problem, doing it without 2 lists for every entry and even no VBA is impossible. (asuming a selection in the second dropdown disables it also in the first)

However, there is a 'halfway' workaround.
The worksheet-function `Cell` (not the VBA function) has a strange behavior when there is no "range" set in target.

```
=Cell("address")
```

will show the address of the "selected" cell (only when calculating the sheet)
Knowing that and pressing `F9` while `$G$13` is selected, it will also show it.

However, now comes the downside :(
For this kind of question it won't help, cuz it refreshes only at each calculation and selecting a different cell doesn't trigger it. While using VBA is not "alowed" by the requestor, it leaves only the "two lists per entry" method.

I'll simply share the WB here. (Writing all of the code here may be to much) :D

[That's the Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_752Ga6Yb7uNUZ4NGVTdnNYRUU/view?usp=sharing)

Sheet 1 needs VBA (calculate sheet)
Sheet 2 does not :P